# 415 unsupported object exception when request body has Map with custom objects as key

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

The request body I have is GameTeamRequest which is as following:

```
public class GameTeamRequest {
    private Game game;  
    private HashMap<Team, Integer> teamsInnigsPostionMap;
}
```

The game object and team object is as follows:

```
public class Game{  
    private String tournamentName;
}
```

Team object is

```
public class Team{
    private String teamName;
}
```

The controller has the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/game", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void createGame(@RequestBody GameTeamRequest gameTeamReq) {
    tournamentService.createGame(gameTeamReq);
}
```

The request payload is as follows:

```
{
    "game": {
        "tournamentName":"Ashes"
     },
    "teamsInnigsPostionMap" : [
    {
        "teamName":"Australia",
        "inningsPosition": "1"
    },
    {
        "teamName":"England",
        "inningsPosition": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am trying to execute, I get the following exception:

```
415 Unsupported Media Type
```

This works perfect when the GameTeamRequest doesn't have maps but just objects. What am I missing when there is map in the request?

UPDATE:

The request URL is `http://localhost:8080/iscorecard/game`

Headers:

Content-Type : application/json

Comment: In your JSON `teamsInnigsPostionMap` is an array, not a hash(map).

Comment: How do you even represent it as a map then? And if this request is wrong it should have thrown me a 400 bad request. Right?

Comment: tell us how you execute the request? please post the full request with request url and request headers.

Comment: Nikolay Rusev: I have updated the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deserialize some JSON to a Map, then the JSON should look something like:

```
{
   "key": { "valueObjectProperty": "valueObjectValue" }
}
```

Note that the keys in JSON object must be Strings, so it would be impossible to deserialize any request to Java map whose key is some custom object. I mean you could probably write some custom deserializer, but that seems like too much of an effort.

It would be better to change the format of your Java classes and consequently the requests you are sending.

For instance (if the team name is unique):

```
public class GameTeamRequest {
    private Game game;  
    private HashMap<String, Integer> teamsInnigsPostionMap;
}
```

then you could send and successufully deserialize request like:

```
{
  "game": {
     "tournamentName":"Ashes"
  },
  "teamsInnigsPostionMap" : {
    "Australia": 1,
    "England": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: It looked correct to me as well. But now getting a 400 bad request error.

Comment: @Arun That's strange. When I use your classes, change them according to my answer and post the JSON I mentioned in my answer, the GameTeamRequest is deserialized successfully.